# Genitiv, der sich auf den Sprecher selbst bezieht

Tags: genitive

Kann eine Konstruktion wie *der Bruder, der sich erhängt hat* zu *der sich erhängte Bruder* umgeformt werden?

Comment: Was hat das mit Genitiv zu tun?

Comment: Nein. Und ich sehe keinen Genitiv.

Comment: @chirlu Anscheinend findet sich "erhangen" auch bei Luther: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FSRTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA569&lpg=PA569&dq=erhangen+oder+erh%C3%A4ngt&source=bl&ots=-sDeHoSImN&sig=QDhZ8rpKDsO1ZzLbtaki-FBJ5_8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCWoVChMI4aL1mZvjyAIVCmg-Ch1feQyu#v=onepage&q=erhangen%20oder%20erh%C3%A4ngt&f=false

Comment: *der sich erhängt habende Bruder.*

Comment: @Ludi: Schon recht, aber Luther ist fast 500 Jahre her. Heute gilt es nicht als standardsprachlich.

Comment: @chirlu Ja. Ich sage es auch nicht, finde es aber in solchen Faellen schwierig zu entscheiden was falsch ist. Gestern sagte ich "ich buk" und kein (anderer) anwesender Muttersprachler verstand mich. In der darauf folgenden Diskussion hielt man "ficht" und "flicht" fuer Praeterita. Es war aber nur als Anmerkung gedacht. Ich bin nicht gegen Ihre Bearbeitung.

Comment: Was ist an dieser Frage unklar? Jemand möchte wissen, ob man einen attributiven Relativsatz in eine attributive Ergänzung (zur Nominalgruppe) umformen kann... - Wie Jan schon gesagt hat: *'der Bruder, der sich erhängt'* -> *'der sich erhängende Bruder'* - *'der Bruder, der sich erhängt hat'* -> *'der sich erhängt habende Bruder'*